# How do I change WeeChat's default nick?

Tags: irc, weechat

WeeChat normally sets the default nick to the user's username.

Is there any way to change this default behavior? I want to specify another nick.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
/set irc.server_default.nicks comma,separated,list,of,nicks
/set irc.server.[SERVER_NAME].nicks "
```

Comment: First line i understoood gives list of names that should be applied, what does second line do ?

Comment: It issues the command specified (/set irc.server.[SERVER_NAME].nicks, but change "[SERVER_NAME]" to any specific server name you want), and repeats (using the shorthand character ") all of the arguments ("comma, ...") from the immediately previous command. This is faster than  having to type them all over again.